# I want to delete all external tables present in a schema in a particular sanbox in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to delete all external tables present in a schema in a particular sanbox in redshift

ERROR  Exception: DROP EXTERNAL TABLE cannot be executed from a function or procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "workspace"."qw"()
AS
$$
DECLARE

```
t_sql                      VARCHAR(32000);
t_script_name              VARCHAR(100) := 'load_sample_dcdr$table_cleanup';
t_table_name               VARCHAR(100);
t_start_runtime             TIMESTAMP;
t_row_count                  BIGINT;
t_current_db_YYYYMM            VARCHAR;
t_current_db            VARCHAR(100);
cur_loop                   REFCURSOR;
```

BEGIN

--  IF UPPER(t_current_db) = UPPER(current_database()) THEN
t_sql := 'select distinct(table_name) from svv_all_columns where schema_name=''deleted'' and database_name=''singh_sandbox''';

```
    OPEN cur_loop FOR EXECUTE t_sql;
       LOOP
        FETCH cur_loop INTO t_table_name;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
             EXECUTE 'DROP  table IF EXISTS deleted.'||t_table_name||' cascade';
           
            t_row_count=t_row_count+1;

       END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_loop;
```

--  END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because DROP EXTERNAL TABLE cannot be run inside a transaction block (BEGIN - END).  This makes running this command inside a stored procedure impossible since the procedure is its own transaction block.  [There are reasons for this but that isn't important for the question.]

So to do this you will need some code running outside of Redshift that can issue the DROP statements outside of a transaction block. Some benches can perform actions like this but most don't.  You could write a Lambda function, or even a bash script can do this if you have the aws and psql clis installed.   Or you can issue the statements manually but that could be a pain if the list of tables is large.